# How to change the backcolor of ToolStripMenuseparator?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a ToolStripMenu that has 3 items(`NewToolStripMenuItem`, `ToolStripMenuItem1`, `CloseToolStripMenuItem`).

`ToolStripMenuItem1` is a separator.

I changed the back color for all items but the separator's backcolor does not change.

How can I change it?

Comment: Instead of setting the BackColor of the items, set the BackColor of the DropDown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your own renderer to paint the separators.
Create a new class eg *customRenderer*

```
Public Class customRenderer
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripRenderer

Protected Overrides Sub OnRenderSeparator(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparatorRenderEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnRenderSeparator(e)

    'Draws the background of the separators. You can draw anything you want
    Dim rect As New Rectangle(0, 0, e.Item.Width, e.Item.Height)
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, rect)
End Sub

End Class
```

In your form load:

```
ToolStrip1.Renderer = New customRenderer
```

Valter